# rosserial_arduino can't send a sensor_msgs/Imu msg

Tags: arduino, imu, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a imu implemented with arduino that I'd like to connect to ros but I got stuck in the most simple thing, sending the Imu message. Sometimes it's it just hang sometimes I get an exception in the python client.

This is the program I'm trying:

```
#include <ros.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/Imu.h>

ros::NodeHandle  nh;

sensor_msgs::Imu imu_msg;
ros::Publisher imu_pub("imu", &imu_msg);


void setup()
{
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(imu_pub);
  imu_msg.header.frame_id = 0;
  imu_msg.orientation.x = 0.0;
  imu_msg.orientation.y = 0.0;
  imu_msg.orientation.z = 0.0;
  imu_msg.orientation.w = 0.0;
}

void loop()
{
  imu_msg.header.stamp = nh.now();
  imu_pub.publish( &imu_msg );
  nh.spinOnce();
  delay(1000);
}
```

And this output of the python serial_node:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1327668877.112084] ROS Serial Python Node
[INFO] [WallTime: 1327668877.115963] Connected on /dev/ttyACM0 at 57600 baud
[INFO] [WallTime: 1327668880.075914] Note: publish buffer size is 512 bytes
[INFO] [WallTime: 1327668880.076318] Setup publisher on imu [sensor_msgs/Imu]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dlobato/ros_workspace/rosserial/rosserial_python/nodes/serial_node.py",         line 58, in <module>
    client.run()
  File     "/home/dlobato/ros_workspace/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 284, in run
    self.callbacks[topic_id](msg)
  File "/home/dlobato/ros_workspace/rosserial/rosserial_python/src/rosserial_python/SerialClient.py", line 95, in handlePacket
    m.deserialize(data)
  File "/opt/ros/electric/stacks/common_msgs/sensor_msgs/src/sensor_msgs/msg/_Imu.py", line 190, in deserialize
    raise roslib.message.DeserializationError(e) #most likely buffer underfill
roslib.message.DeserializationError: unpack requires a string argument of length 72
```

If I just change the type of message it works fine, so I think either there's some kind of bug regarding the Imu message or I can't see the problem.

Any idea is welcome! Thanks!
David.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12782/rosserial_arduino-can%27t-send-a-sensor_msgs/imu-msg/) by [dlobato](https://answers.ros.org/users/1701/dlobato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-01-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason is that the message is just too big for the arduino. There might be some other related questions on this if you look for it.

I did not find a satisfying solution besides sending a float multi array and filling out an Imu message from that manually.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3